# How does the page.py file and the element.py file interact on the Selenium PageObject tutorial? What is the BasePageElement?

Tags: python, selenium, pageobjects

Based on user input on a search engine, I am trying to scrape data from the search results on a website through multiple layers. The search results of the user may vary so I decided to use the PageObject design pattern to scale my project, but I don't understand the Python Selenium tutorial and how the element.py file and page.py file interact so I can edit them to my liking.

I am following this tutorial: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

What is the BasePageElement? Is this file only apply to the first layer for webscraping? Should I copy the BasePageElement class and edit it for the next layer in my webscraping journey into a website? Is there a better explanation on what the element.py file is actually doing?

Comment: I would copy `BasePageElement` or file `element.py` and import it and later use to create own class `class SomeElement(BasePageElement)` without changing original `BasePageElement`. You even have it in your link - `class SearchTextElement(BasePageElement)`. The same with class `BasePage` - copy it and use it to create own class - ie. `class MainPage(BasePage):`

Comment: I feel like they dont explain the page element code so I get completely lost.

Comment: it is not important what is in classes, every class will need different methods - all depends what you will need. In `BasePage` you will put methods which you will need in all other subclasses. And in subclasses you put methods which you need to get interesting elements. They show examples for `http://www.python.org` but for othe pages you will need different method in classes.

Comment: similar with `BasePageElement` - it has two methods which will be usefull with all other subclasses. It uses `self.locator` to get/set value and in other subclasses you have to add it - ie. in `class SearchTextElement(BasePageElement):` you have `locator = 'q'` to get search field on `http://www.python.org` - but on other pages you may need different locator. And if you will need to access different element then you will have to create differn subclass.

Comment: I will create another Class Element for the next page on page.py because it has a different locator...

Comment: for every element you should create separate subclass - ie. `SearchTextElement(BasePageElement)`, `ArticleHeaderElement(BasePageElement)`, `ArticleDateElement(BasePageElement)` `ArticleImageElement(BasePageElement)`, `ArticleAuthorElement(BasePageElement)`, etc.. This way you organize code - ie. you use `ArticleAuthorElement` only to get `author` but not `date`, because you have `ArticleDateElement` to get `date` and in `ArticleAuthorElement` you add localor for `author` and add function which you may need to get `author` - you can add function to clear it - ie, remove spaces at the end.

Comment: I just dont get why they create two locator classes. Page.py locators and locators.py locators. Seems redundant.

Comment: I see it in different way. Class `Locator` keeps only value used in `find_element-by_...` and it has no function to use this value. Class `Element` gets `Locator` and it uses `find_element-by_...` to find it, get value or set value. It could also have functions to process value (remove spaces, convert to lower case, etc). `Element` works only with one element on page. You can have two different `Element` with the same `Locator` but use them on different pages. Class `Page` is not locator - it groups many `Element` used on page.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the explanation. So on the element.py file, would it be advisable to edit the __set__ method. I need to add the Keys.RETURN function to finding my target element and I don't want to affect it when other functions call the BasePageElement Class.

Comment: you don't have to change `__set__` but use it with `[your_text, Keys.RETURN]`. Not all elements may need `Keys.RETURN` - sometimes you have to put text in all elements in form before you can click RETURN (or some button) to send all data to server

Comment: I am still having a hard time finding a location for the location of send_keys() method. I tried putting it in my MainPage(BasePage) class and use search_text_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN), but my search_text_element is not a web element. The locator has found the search bar and inserted the text given. It just hasn't pressed submit.

Comment: if you really need it then you should modify original `BasePageElement` and add it after `send_key(value)` or even use `send_key( [value, Keys.RETURN] )` But I would keep original version and use `search_text_element = [value, Keys.RETURN]`

Comment: Sorry to bother again. where does search_text_element = [value, Keys.RETURN] go again? i have search_text_element variable right after the MainPage class.

Comment: I put example with `search_text_element = [value, Keys.RETURN]` as answer - there is more space for code. And it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for page `Stackoveflow`

But current classes have two problems for me:

- `BasePageElement` uses only `find_element_by_name` and it is useless to search elements different then fields in form.
- `BasePageElement` search on single element so it is useless to get all results on search page.

It would need other classes to make it more useful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

# --- original classes ---

class BasePage(object):
    """Base class to initialize the base page that will be called from all pages"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

class BasePageElement(object):
    """Base page class that is initialized on every page object class."""

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        """Sets the text to the value supplied"""
        driver = obj.driver

        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator))
        driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator).send_keys(value)
        #driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator).send_keys(Keys.Return)

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        """Gets the text of the specified object"""
        driver = obj.driver
        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator))
        element = driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator)
        return element.get_attribute("value")

# --- my classes ---

class SearchTextElement(BasePageElement):

    locator = 'q'

class MainPage(BasePage):

    # element has to be defined here 
    # (not as `self.field` because it will not work as expected)
    search_text_element = SearchTextElement()

    def search(self, query):
        self.search_text_element = [query, Keys.RETURN]

# ---- 

class ResultElement(BasePageElement):

    locator = 'q' # there is no other `name` on Stackoveflow

class ResultPage(BasePage):

    # element has to be defined here 
    # (not as `self.field` because it will not work as expected)
    result_element = ResultElement()

    def get_result(self):
        return self.result_element

# --- main ---

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

main_page = MainPage(driver)
main_page.search('selenium')

result_page = ResultPage(driver)
result = result_page.get_result()
print('result:', result)
```

Comment: Thanks! Its almost done with my code. The Keys.RETURN button still needs to activate.

Comment: I think the PAGE OBJECT DESIGN PATTERN finally clicked! Thanks for all your help.